# Malformed Address '10.10.21.08/24', must be X.X.X.X/NN or

Tags: ip, netplan

I am trying to set a static IP for my ubuntu server by creating a yaml file on /etc/netplan/ as follows:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd        
    ethernets:
        enp0s3:
            dhcp4: no
            addresses: [10.10.21.08/24]
            gateway4: 10.10.21.100
```

But `sudo netplan apply` returns an error:

```
Error in network definition /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml line 6 column 23: Malformed Address '10.10.21.08/24',  must be X.X.X.X/NN or ... ".
```

Comment: Have you tried "[10.10.21.8/24]" (without the leading zero before the 8)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error code indicates that there is a `"Malformed Address"` in `"10.10.21.08/24"`.

Try leaving out the leading zero in the fourth octet (i.e. write `'10.10.21.8/24'`).

Comment: FYI the reason for this is for most integer to strong converters if you prefix a decimal number with 0 it attempts to parse the following as an octal number, and 8 is not a valid octal digit.